# Regex expression to filter email

Tags: regex, email, filter

I am getting spam from fake ADT.

I had written a regex filter as following to discard any message that contains ADT in the from field but not if it comes from adt.com or adt.ca.

```
(?i).*adt.*^(adt.com|adt.ca)
```

But I tested it and it didn't prevent an email coming from this email :

```
    ADT Authorized <adt@eliteavd.com>
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a negative lookahead like below,

```
^(?!.*(?:adt\.com|adt\.ca)).*?adt.*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kW2qS3/1)

Comment: I used this answer with some modifications. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey, what happens when I want to do it with an email that doesn't have adt in it at all?

Example : ADT Systems <fake@notreallythem.com>

Comment: sorry i don't know what you mean.Did you want to match the above or not

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$re = "/adt\\.(com|ca)/mi";
$str = "adt.com\nadt.ca\nAuthorized <adt@eliteavd.com>\n";

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

[**live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/pE9bV5/2)

Answer (score 0):

I used a version of Avinash Raj's solution.

```
^(?!.*(?:adt\.com|adt\.ca)).*(?i)adt
```

Thanks!